# Glue PySpark Error: pyWriteDynamicFrame. org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have been over 2 days debugging and trying to figure out what's going on, without success. AWS Support has not been able to help me here either, so let me explain.

I have a table called `provisioned.customer` which is defined on Glue. This table is on provisioned database.

[image]

I have another 2 tables, `curated.customer_consents` and `curated.customer` with their respective schemas:

[image]

[image]

I have set all data types to string for easing the process.

Now I have a Glue job 3.0 with PySpark, and the following code:

```
# more imports...
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def fudf(val):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, val)

flattenUdf = F.udf(fudf, T.StringType())

customer_df = spark.read.table('curated.customer')
core_customer_consents_df = spark.read.table('curated.core_customer_consents')

core_customer_consents_df = core_customer_consents_df.groupBy("tscid").agg(F.collect_list('purpose').alias('__purposes__'))

merged = customer_df.join(core_customer_consents_df, ['tscid'], how='inner')
merged = merged.select("*", flattenUdf("__purposes__").alias("cirrus_purposes"))
merged = merged.select([c for c in merged.columns if c not in {'__purposes__'}])
logger.info(merged)

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=DynamicFrame.fromDF(merged, glueContext, "a"),
    database = 'provisioned', 
    table_name = 'customer', 
    transformation_ctx = "datasource0", 
)
```

This is the output of the `logger.info`:

```
2022-06-15 08:35:26 INFO logger: DataFrame[tscid: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, gender: string, birthdate: string, qualification: string, country: string, estimated_annual_earning: string, cirrus_purposes: string]
```

But after executing this, I face the following issue:

```
An error occurred while calling o149.pyWriteDynamicFrame. org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainLongDictionary
```

[image]

But I have checked schema matching and they are exactly the same (see `logger.info` output) and even in the same column order. Also in my local this does generate the data frame accordingly. So I don't know what's really going on.

Have you faced this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. I was generating from CSV using pyarrow parquet files. Column `estimated_annual_earning` was being generated as long. So whenever I was reading it, apparently no issues due to the lazy nature, but it gave this error when the action (insert) was called, due to a mismatch between data type when reading `curated.customer`.

Solution: generate parquet with the same data types as what you have in your glue metastore.